# multiple instances of C# DataTable stored in session ..how this reference works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, reference, instance

I have a problem with `DataTable` stored in `Session` and code execution when retrieving it from this `Session`. Maybe this isn't a problem and is just me wrongly understanding how instances and references really work.

I have a POCO class `User` where I store all the data of logged in user. The POCO Class look like this:

```
public class User 
{
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
   public string UserLastName { get; set; }
   public DataTable UserRights { get; set; }
}
```

Once the user is logged in (on login page) I create an instance of `User` class and I store all retrieved data from login into `Session["User"]`:

```
User _user = new User();
_user = MyLogin.GetUser() // method returns filled User object with data from db
Session["User"] = _user; // I store it into session
```

Then on my pages when I need data from Session for user rights (stored in datatable) I look into session and retrieve DataTable:

```
User _currUser = (User)Session["User"];
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = _currUser.UserRights;
```

This code works OK, but some strange behavior starts when I look into Session for DataTable UserRights **multiple times on the same page**.

Example: I have two user controls on page and in each one of them I look into session for DataTable like in the code above. Then if I change DataTable object instance in one of the user controls code like this for example:

```
dt.Columns.Remove("RoleID");
```

...this change impacts the instance in second user control too(??). And the same goes if give instances different names:

```
// FirstUserControl.ascx.cs
User _currUser1 = (User)Session["User"];
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1 = _currUser1.UserRights;
dt1.Columns.Remove("RoleID")

// SecondUserControl.ascx.cs
User _currUser2 = (User)Session["User"];
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = _currUser2.UserRights; <--- dt2 is without column "RoleID" too!?
```

Can somebody in a clear way explain to me why this is happening and how instances and references works in this example (it looks I don't understand them correctly). I always thought that if I execute code like the one above I would get `dt1` and `dt2` `DataTable` object which will not have anything in common when processing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable is a reference type, dt1 and dt2 are just memory addresses to the chunk of memory holding the datatable, they always refer to the same object.

In this case you can use [DataTable.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)

```
User _currUser1 = (User)Session["User"];
DataTable dt1 = _currUser1.UserRights.Copy();
dt1.Columns.Remove("RoleID")

// SecondUserControl.ascx.cs
User _currUser2 = (User)Session["User"];
DataTable dt2 = _currUser2.UserRights.Copy();
```